# How to open multiple windows with jQuery/js and trigger a form submit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, new-window

Given a comma-separated string of URLs, I want to open a separate window for each element of its *converted-to* array, then submit a form.

The following code only opens one window, and no form submit takes place:

```
$.each(urlList.split(","), function (index, item) {

    urlList = "http://www.cnn.com,http://www.foxnews.com";

    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Results', 'Click', 'Classifieds+: ' + item + ' : ' + SourceUrlProviderID]);
    window.open(item, "_blank");
});
document.forms[0].submit();
```

When I do the following, I get the desired action - three new tabs/windows open, but I it looks like the form submit would be done twice and doesn't quite make sense:

```
urlList = "http://www.cnn.com,http://www.foxnews.com";

// opens windows for each URL in the string
$.each(urlList.split(","), function (index, item) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Results', 'Click', 'Classifieds+: ' + item + ' : ' + SourceUrlProviderID]);
    document.forms[0].submit();
    window.open(item, "_blank");
});
```

Can someone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `urlList` is inside `$.each`? Anyway, I tried this, and works:

```
var urlList = "http://www.cnn.com,http://www.foxnews.com"
$.each( urlList.split( "," ), function( index, item ) {
    window.open( item, "_blank" )
});
document.forms[0].submit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the urlList catch... should have been *item*.  Tried that code, and still only one window opens.  With the document.forms[0].submit in the loop before the window.open, it works fine - three windows appear.  The third windows is opened by the submit().

Comment: What do you mean the "should have been item"? Please update your code to correct one.

Answer (score 0):

you should submit the form just out of the loop (each in this case) if you cannot do that just check if it is the last item.

```
if (index == urlList.split(",").length)
   document.forms[0].submit();
```

but to be honest this does not look like a correct way to do. Why you are submitting the form if just for the stats you can use a simple AJAX call.

Comment: The code started out with a Razor MVC3 form post request, where the parameters are read by the controller.  Trying to not re-wire the whole thing.

Comment: you can submit the code by jQuery ajax post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example